# iOS 11 UISearchController.searchBar have a blackColor view

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios11, uisearchcontroller

I am using the following code for setting up the search controller

```
_searchController = [[UISearchController alloc]initWithSearchResultsController:self.resultVC];
self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
_searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = YES;
_searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = YES;
_searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
// 可以通过此种方式可以拿到搜索框，修改搜索框的样式
UITextField *searchField = [_searchController.searchBar valueForKey:@"_searchField"];
searchField.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
searchField.leftView = nil;
searchField.layer.cornerRadius = 4;
searchField.clipsToBounds = YES;
searchField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever;

UIView *backgroundview = searchField.subviews.firstObject;
backgroundview.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

[image: UI]

While looking through the view hierarchy, I found a view that I never added

[image: the hierarchical chart]

I tried to delete this view but I couldn't because `backgroundview` doesn't have any subview

```
NSInteger count = backgroundview.subviews;
for (UIView *sub in backgroundview.subviews) {
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass(sub.class));// don't have any subView
}
```

How can I delete this particular view?

Comment: What issues are you facing because of that?

Comment: You shouldn't be touching the internals of Apple's search bar. They way you are getting a reference to the text field is considered a "hack" because you are using private API's. Anyway, if you are using this access only to change a color or two maybe its fine, but it does not seem unreasonable to suggest that apple will not be that happy during the app review if you remove one of their internal views. Also when you are using private API's there is no guarantee that in the next SDK version this reference will still be there.